# Куда передаёт блок yield в Rails приложении?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Довольно часто вижу, что в коде бывает 
 `<%= yield %>` . Как это понимать? Куда передаётся блок? К примеру, используется в файле application.html.erb

И ещё вопрос насчёт `<%= ... %>` и `<% ... %>`. Что это конкретно значит и почему иногда в начале `%=`, а иногда просто `%`. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` в общем случае передаёт управление на блок, переданный методу:

```
def foo
  yield
end
foo { puts "bar" }
#> bar   <- вывод
# => nil <- возвращаемое значение
```

В случае с Rails это связано с системой представлений (views). Как правило, view это страница конкретного экшена, завёрнутая в макет (layout). Блоки и `yield` как раз управляют этим заворачиванием.

Если сильно упрощать, то это примерно такой вызов:

```
layout_view do
  action_view
end
```

Реальная реализация посложнее: она также позволяет передавать блоку аргумент (`yield :something`), чтобы выводить одноимённый блок, определённый в экшене с помощью `content_for`. Но я сильно отдалился от сути вопроса. Подробнее в [руководствах](http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails).

#### Трюк

Любопытно, но если во вьюхе сделать так:

```
<%= render 'some_partial' do %>
  <b>Text</b>
<% end %>
```

...когда в `some_partial` так же используется `yield`, всё сломается. Исправляется это довольно неочевидно: `render partial: 'some_partial' do`

#### Про `<%` и `<%=`

Всё просто. У того, что вы вызываете в этой конструкции, может быть возвращаемое значение. Если `=` есть, то оно выводится во вьюху (как в `<%= @user.name %>`). Если нет, то действие выполняется, но ничего само по себе не выводит:

```
<%= [1, 2, 3].each do |i| %>
  <div><%= "Номер #{i}" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Максимум, что можно перепутать -- это вывести то, что выводить не надо, как в примере выше. Метод `each` возвращает то, на чём был вызван. Эта конструкция не только выведет три `<div>`'а, но и сам массив. Этого вам, скорее всего, не надо, поэтому в первой конструкции должно быть `<%`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, очень информативно!

Answer (score 1):

**Про <%= ... %> и <% ... %>**. Это синтаксис **erb**,означающий что в этом теге руби код и его нужно соответствующем образом выполнить. Разница между <%= и <% в том,что в 1м случае всё что будет возвращено руби кодом будет вставлено в html разметку. Так можете почитать про haml...

**yield** это "оператор" руби,который вызывает(выполняет) переданный блок кода. В контексте rails и  application.html.erb представьте что заместо yield подставляется какое то конкретное представление представление.